# When using a Style to set the Icon of a MenuItem only the last item displays the icon

Tags: wpf, contextmenu

I'm trying to use a Style to set the Icon for all MenuItems in a ContextMenu

```
<Grid>
<Button Content="Open Context Menu">
   <Button.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu>
     <ContextMenu.Resources>               
          <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
              <Setter Property="Header" Value="Click Me"/>                                    
              <Setter Property="Icon">
                  <Setter.Value>
                      <Ellipse Width="16" Height="16" Fill="Red"/>
                  </Setter.Value>
              </Setter>
          </Style>
      </ContextMenu.Resources>        
    <MenuItem/>
    <MenuItem/>
    </ContextMenu>
   </Button.ContextMenu>
</Button>
```

As a result only the last MenuItem in the ContextMenu gets an Ellipse icon

[image]

If I set the Icon manually for each MenuIcon I get the expected result:

```
<Grid>
<Button Content="Open Context Menu">
   <Button.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu>
     <ContextMenu.Resources>               
          <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
              <Setter Property="Header" Value="Click Me"/>                                    
          </Style>
      </ContextMenu.Resources>        
      <MenuItem>
        <MenuItem.Icon>
          <Ellipse Width="16" Height="16" Fill="Red"/>
        </MenuItem.Icon>
      </MenuItem>
      <MenuItem>
       <MenuItem.Icon>
          <Ellipse Width="16" Height="16" Fill="Red"/>
       </MenuItem.Icon>
      </MenuItem>
      </ContextMenu>
   </Button.ContextMenu>
</Button>
```

[image]

Any idea what might be causing this behavior and how to solve it?

*I'm aware there is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19235316/only-the-last-menuitem-gets-the-icon), but it doesn't directly solve my issue.*

**Update:** I found a solution in a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6177550/menuitem-style-with-icon-creates-only-one-icon?rq=1).

The key is to use `x:Shared="false"`:

```
<Grid>
<Button Content="Open Context Menu">
   <Button.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu>
     <ContextMenu.Resources>               
      <Ellipse x:Key="MenuIcon" x:Shared="false" 
               Width="16" Height="16" Fill="Red"/>
        <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
              <Setter Property="Header" Value="Click Me"/>                                    
              <Setter Property="Icon" Value="{StaticResource MenuIcon"/>                                      
          </Style>
      </ContextMenu.Resources>                  
      <MenuItem/>
      <MenuItem/>          
      </ContextMenu>
   </Button.ContextMenu>
</Button>
```

I incorrectly assumed it didn't work / apply to my situation
because I was testing in [KaXaml](http://www.kaxaml.com/) which doesn't support this.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding

x:Shared="False"

(note that is does work in VS but not in Kaxaml :p )

Comment: Right after I told you :p